# How do I find the currently selected (or active) Row in an UltraGrid

Tags: .net, ultrawingrid

Using the Infragistics UltraGrid (e.g. `myGrid`), I want to:

1. Hook an event that will fire when active row is changed (selected, clicked, etc).
2. Do something with the selection

**SUMMARY ANSWER**

1. Subscribe to event `AfterRowActivate`
2. Get a reference to `myGrid.ActiveRow`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following [page](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/NET/2008.2/CLR2.0/html/WinGrid_AfterRowActivate_Event.html) talks about the event fired when the active row has changed.

To get the active row, you can use the property **yourGrid.ActiveRow** or **yourGrid.Selected.Rows** to get all selected rows.

Comment: that link is dead but i think this shud work http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid~AfterRowActivate_EV.html for anyone still looking for this.